# How to add watermark to the video part of this huge ffmpeg command that adds intro and outro with crossfade?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I wrote a command that crossfade merge an intro, an outro, with a video:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[intro]; 
[0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[firstfadeoutclip]; 
[1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[firstfadeinclip]; 
[1:v]trim=start=1:end=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[video]; 
[1:v]trim=start=24:end=25,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[secondfadeoutclip]; 
[2:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[secondfadeinclip]; 
[2:v]trim=start=1:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[outro]; 
[firstfadeoutclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[firstfadeoutalpha]; 
[firstfadeinclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[firstfadeinalpha]; 
[secondfadeoutclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[secondfadeoutalpha]; 
[secondfadeinclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[secondfadeinalpha]; 
[firstfadeoutalpha]fifo[firstfadeoutfifo]; 
[firstfadeinalpha]fifo[firstfadeinfifo]; 
[secondfadeoutalpha]fifo[secondfadeoutfifo]; 
[secondfadeinalpha]fifo[secondfadeoinfifo]; 
[firstfadeoutfifo][firstfadeinfifo]overlay[firstcrossfade]; 
[secondfadeoutfifo][secondfadeoinfifo]overlay[secondcrossfade]; 
[intro][firstcrossfade][video][secondcrossfade][outro]concat=n=5[output]; 
[0:a][1:a] acrossfade=d=1 [audio]" 
-vcodec libx264 -map "[output]" -map "[audio]" "output.mp4"
```

This huge command works fine.

But now what I want to do is to add a watermark to the video part:

```
[1:v]trim=start=1:end=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[video];
```

And I want to do it by merging this command (watermark) into that one above:

```
ffmpeg -i "1080p.mp4" -filter_complex "
movie=logo-wm.png[watermark];
[watermark][0:V]scale2ref=(1917*iw/1920)/3.5:(322*iw/1920)/3.5[wm][v]; 
[v][logo]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-20:20" "output.mp4"
```

The whole `(1917*iw/1920)/3.5:(322*iw/1920)/3.5` scales the watermark proportionally using the `scale2ref=` filter. The `1917` is the width of my watermark image, and `322` is the height

It is overlayed in the top right corner with `main_w-overlay_w-20:20`

But I can't make it work I tried to add it by copying the parameters to the filter of `[1:v]` input. And by adding another input for the watermark that if I'm right it would be `[3:v]` instead of using the `movie=` filter. But I can't.

I know that I could do it in two steps, but I would like to do it at once, in just one command.

May anyone help me to merge them ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[intro]; 
[0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[firstfadeoutclip];
[3:v][1:v]scale2ref=(1917*iw/1920)/3.5:(322*iw/1920)/3.5[wm][v1ol];
[v1ol]trim=0:25[v1];[v1][wm]overlay=W-w-20:20,split=3[1va][1vb][1vc];
[1va]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[firstfadeinclip];
[1vb]trim=start=1:end=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[video]; 
[1vc]trim=start=24:end=25,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[secondfadeoutclip]; 
[2:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[secondfadeinclip]; 
[2:v]trim=start=1:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=480x360,setsar=sar=16/9[outro]; 
[firstfadeoutclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[firstfadeoutalpha]; 
[firstfadeinclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[firstfadeinalpha]; 
[secondfadeoutclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[secondfadeoutalpha]; 
[secondfadeinclip]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[secondfadeinalpha]; 
[firstfadeoutalpha]fifo[firstfadeoutfifo]; 
[firstfadeinalpha]fifo[firstfadeinfifo]; 
[secondfadeoutalpha]fifo[secondfadeoutfifo]; 
[secondfadeinalpha]fifo[secondfadeoinfifo]; 
[firstfadeoutfifo][firstfadeinfifo]overlay[firstcrossfade]; 
[secondfadeoutfifo][secondfadeoinfifo]overlay[secondcrossfade]; 
[intro][firstcrossfade][video][secondcrossfade][outro]concat=n=5[output]; 
[0:a][1:a] acrossfade=d=1 [audio]" 
-vcodec libx264 -map "[output]" -map "[audio]" "output.mp4"
```

(I haven't checked the rest of your command, but maybe you meant to use `setdar=16/9`)

Comment: The command works but the watermark disappears after 1 or 2 seconds... Looks like if the trim duration wasn't properly applied. I used setsar because in the docs i've read that it also set the dar. If I used setsar in all the streams shouldn't I use the same in the stream for the watermark ?

Comment: I think the watermark is only applied to the `[firstfadeinclip]` but not to `[video]` and [`secondfadeoutclip`] I'm trying...

Comment: Corrected. Generated streams need to be duplicated for reuse, unlike source streams.